# Java synchronized method documentation seems wrong

Tags: java, multithreading

The Oracle [lesson on concurrency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) states:

> it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave.

However, if a non-static synchronized method contains a call to `wait()`, this releases the thread's ownership of the object's monitor, thus allowing another thread to enter a synchronized method. Am I misunderstanding `wait()`, or is this not considered interleaving?

Comment: This is not considered interleaving. Only one thread is awake inside the synchronized block at a time.

Comment: @AndyTurner You should post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not considered interleaving.

Only one thread is awake inside the synchronized block at a time.